# How do I call a Python function with parameters from an HTML page (alongside Django)?

Tags: python, django, http

I'm in the process of writing a Django app, but I've hit a slight roadblock.

You see, I have the backend return an HTML page, and that works just fine. What I am having trouble with though is going the other way around. I am trying to call a function on the backend once the user clicks a button. Now, I've already searched to see if anyone else has asked this question before, but all the posts that came up had a different scenario linked to them. All of them were for GET requests, but I need to be able to POST some data instead.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to get started with Django forms:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/

Forms accept a `POST`, and there are lots of handy parts for sanitizing the data.